# Flutter run async operation on object creation

Tags: api, asynchronous, dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter and I know it's a very basic question but I've been stuck on this one for three days. I just want to fetch data from an API on object creation. When you run the code it throws an exception But when you Hot Reload it, the async operation starts to work fine. Kindly tell me where I'm wrong. I myself have made extra classes although one should avoid to code with that approach.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main(){
    runApp(
       MaterialApp(
        title : "Quake",
        home :  HomePage()
      )
    );
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataRepository.init();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Reading();
  }
}
class Reading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReadingState createState() => _ReadingState();
}
class _ReadingState extends State<Reading> {
  Map _data = Map();
  List _features = List();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data = dataRepository.getReading();
    _features = _data['features'];
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
        appBar:  AppBar(
          title:  Text("Quake"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body :  Center(
            child :  ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _features.length,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.5),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position){
                var format =  DateFormat.yMMMd("en_US").add_jm();
                var _date = format.format( DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(_features[position]['properties']['time']*1000, isUtc: true));
                return  Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Divider(height : 5.5),
                    ListTile(
                      title:  Text("$_date",
                          style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
                      subtitle:  Text("${_features[position]['properties']['place']}",
                          style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                      leading:  CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor : Colors.black,
                          child :  Text("${_features[position]['properties']['mag']}", style:  TextStyle( color: Colors.white))
                      ),
                      onTap: () => _windowOnTapping(context, _features[position]['properties']['title']),
            )],);},)));}}

Future _windowOnTapping(BuildContext context, String message){
  var alert =  AlertDialog(
    title:  Text("Quakes"),
    content:  Text(message),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton ( child:  Text("OK"), onPressed: (){ Navigator.pop(context);})
    ],
  );
  showDialog( context: context, builder: (context)=> alert);
}
final DataRepository dataRepository = DataRepository._private();
class DataRepository{
  DataRepository._private();
  Map _data;
  void init() async{
    String apiUrl = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson';
    http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
    _data = json.decode(response.body);
  }
  Map getReading(){
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use futurebuilder

Comment: I think that your dataRepository.init() just creates Future. It will be executed in the future. Your dataRepository is not initialized before calling dataRepository.getReading(). Inside init() initialize dataRepository.streamOfData and feed it to the FutureBuilder. When you run hot reload dataRepository is already initialized. Or you can do dataRepository.init().then(showMyDataInAWidget());

Comment: Wow! Two earthquake apps in a week. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526977/flutter-stateful-code-problem-what-to-put-in-setstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to read the Future and only render the component after it returns, something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(title: "Quake", home: HomePage()));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Reading();
  }
}

class Reading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReadingState createState() => _ReadingState();
}

class _ReadingState extends State<Reading> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Quake"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<Map>(
            future: dataRepository.getReading(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var features = snapshot.data['features'];
                return Center(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: features.length,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.5),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                    var format = DateFormat.yMMMd("en_US").add_jm();
                    var _date = format.format(
                        DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(
                            features[position]['properties']['time'] * 1000,
                            isUtc: true));
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Divider(height: 5.5),
                        ListTile(
                          title:
                              Text("$_date", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              "${features[position]['properties']['place']}",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                              child: Text(
                                  "${features[position]['properties']['mag']}",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                          onTap: () => _windowOnTapping(context,
                              features[position]['properties']['title']),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ));
              } else {
                return Text("Loading");
              }
            }));
  }
}

Future _windowOnTapping(BuildContext context, String message) {
  var alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Quakes"),
    content: Text(message),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
          child: Text("OK"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          })
    ],
  );
  showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => alert);
}

final DataRepository dataRepository = DataRepository._private();

class DataRepository {
  DataRepository._private();

  Future<Map> getReading() async {
    String apiUrl =
        'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson';
    http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data);
    return data;
  }
}
```